# Как создать клон View?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-layout, android-layout-inflater

Как создать клон `View`?

Я создаю `View` в xml указываю там стиль цвет размеры и т.д.

Хочу в программно создать клон этого `View`.

Что то типо `View view2=myXmlView`
Но объект не создается. Как сделать клон исходя из XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам требуется `LayoutInflater`. С его помощью это делается так:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.NAME_OF_XML_FILE_IN_RES_LAYOUT, null, false);
View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.NAME_OF_XML_FILE_IN_RES_LAYOUT, null, false);
```

Comment: А после сделать View myView=view1

И я получу клон view компонента?

Comment: @EraNewGames, нет, так вы присвоите переменной myView ссылку на объект, на который ссылается в т.ч. и переменная view1. Кажется вам надо раскрыть ваше понимание понятия `клон` - что именно вы хотите получить и чего этим добиться?

Comment: Видимо не так объяснил. Я не хочу получать ссылку на объект View. Я хочу создать TextView программно, но так чтобы оно выглядело как в XML. Так можно сделать?

Просто в XML наглядно выглядит и там удобно создать Viewшку. А после динамически программно эту же вьюшку копировать и сделать допустим штук 10. Вообщем кол-во от данных сервера зависит. Вот что я хочу. А вы наверное имели ввиду что Клон это двойник. Мне не двойник нужен, а копия. Выглядит как оригинал но ссылка другая)). Вроде все

Comment: @EraNewGames, ну в ответе как раз то что вам нужно - в переменных view1 и view2 как раз идентичные вьюхи сформированные из одного и того же xml файла но при этом они по сути два отдельных объекта. Т.е. если надо 10 вьюх разных из одной разметки - создайте 10 переменных и каждую инициализируйте как в ответе написано.

Comment: Ок то что надо было) спасибо

Comment: Юрий. А почему через R.id.IDVIEW, null, false не работает?

Comment: @EraNewGames, потому что метод требует именно разметку, а не ID.